# iexplorer.exe behaving differently remote vs local when same content is loaded on same browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have no idea what would cause this, but the exact same code on the host site and local server is interpreted differently by the same iexplore browser.  The CSS nav bar (see code below)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>site</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
font-family: "Helvetica";
}

#master {
width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; 
}
#Banner {
height: 153px;
width: 960px;
}
#navMenu {
height: 40px;
width: 960px;
font-size: 14px;
}
.div1 {
margin: 0px;
}
.div1 ul li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
ul li a {
color: #FBF7F7;
background-color: #353333;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 136px;
height: 38px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 38px;
border-left: thin solid #CCCCCC;
}
ul li a:hover {
background-color: #666666;
}
.noBorder {
border-left-style: none !important; 
}
.leftEdge {
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.rigthEdge {
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="master">

<div id="Banner"><img src="web_banner.jpg" width="960" height="150" alt=""/>       </div>

<div id="navMenu">
<div class="div1">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" class="noBorder leftEdge">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="submit_report.php">Submit Report</a></li>
<li><a href="search_square.php">Search Square</a></li>
<li><a href="species_info.php">Species Info</a></li>
<li><a href="resources.php">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php" class="rigthEdge">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

on the local server (MAMP) the menu list items are properly displayed within the navbar div (spacing and outer edges rounded).  When that same code is loaded from the host site, the rounded edges of the outer list are lost and the last list value is wrapped underneath the first (if I change the px to 135, it moves it back up to the proper position in the nav bar but still no rounded edges).

I am completely confused what would cause this behavior?  Has anyone experienced this before and potentially know a solution?

Comment: Sounds like your CSS doesn't load when runned from the host site. Have you checked the file path is correct? ... You can easily test that by taking the CSS path from the generated html and run that in your browser, and if all is okay it should load/download the CSS

Comment: the css is within the page not an external file

Comment: Is there additional css being injected by the host?

Comment: In that case, you need to post a minimal code snippet that reproduce the issue so we have with what to work.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the css code and the nav menu lists. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, this kind of problem in Explorer is due to it's Local Intranet settings, which default to displaying local pages in IE7 compatibility mode.

Look through IE's config to find this setting and switch it off, and you should find that the pages start to render correctly when it's on your local machine.

You can also add the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag to your HTML code to force IE to ignore this setting and display in a specific mode (preferably "edge" mode, as this tells it to use the best mode available).

Comment: fantastic, this fixed the problem....now to see why recaptcha is acting stupid in iexplore....for a very popular browser it appears to be a big pain in the rear